# BoneCP sometimes cannot get config from spring property holder

Tags: spring, bonecp

I have been facing this issue for a while now. My config is as following

```
<!-- Load Properties Files -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*-${environment}.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="${boneCP.idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes}"/>
        <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="${boneCP.idleMaxAgeInMinutes}"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="${boneCP.maxConnectionsPerPartition}"/>
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="${boneCP.minConnectionsPerPartition}"/>
        <property name="partitionCount" value="${boneCP.partitionCount}"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${boneCP.acquireIncrement}"/>
        <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="${boneCP.statementsCacheSize}"/>
        <property name="lazyInit" value="true"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionAgeInSeconds" value="${boneCP.maxConnectionAgeInSeconds}"/>
</bean>
```

The project is running on Tomcat 7

On the local machine, the project deploy with no error as well as for the dev server. Unfortunately, the project cannot be deployed on dev server any more (server configuration remain same) while local machine is still fine. Every time I deploy the project on the dev server, Tomcat just hang at INFO: Deploying web application archive /etc/tomcat/webapps/project.war. But if I config BoneCP with real values, everything is fine.

Could any one tell me what's wrong with it?

---

It turned out to be the lazyInit problem. If I comment it out, the server can start normally. But now I'm facing the new issue though. Mybatis cannot access the db at all while the local machine is 100% fine. and yet dont throw any exception. But when I stop the server, I found the following exceptions

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolUtil.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.DefaultConnectionStrategy.getConnectionInternal(DefaultConnectionStrategy.java:94)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.AbstractConnectionStrategy.getConnection(AbstractConnectionStrategy.java:90)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.getConnection(BoneCP.java:540)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:131)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.openConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:80)
    at org.mybatis.spring.transaction.SpringManagedTransaction.getConnection(SpringManagedTransaction.java:66)
```

AND

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ExceptionUtil.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:363)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy15.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:195)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:124)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:90)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy45.selectByExample(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it could be many things but its most likely

1. properties are not being replaced with the values you think
2. the database number of connections has been exceeded or the wrong host
3. A combination of 1 + 2

For #1 I would a make a separate bean that needs com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource as a dependency and have it print out the getters of BoneCPDataSource.

For #2 I would turn on as much logging as possible (see log4j or logback or whatever your logging framework is).